# Parametric equation for y^2 = x+1

Tags: parametric

How do you parametrise 
$$y^2 = x+1$$
?

I only know how to parametrise a circle.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options

For example

Set $y=t$. so that  $x=t^2-1$ simplest, right?

Or $y=p+1,x=(p+1)^2-1$

Comment: I thought it was also done with sin and cos?

Comment: That would require sum of two squares, right

Comment: Because we parametrise ellipses and circles with sin and cos, so I expected something with sin and cos :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use $$y=tx$$ so we get $$x^2-\frac{1}{t^2}x-\frac{1}{t^2}=0$$ and we get $$x_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{2t^2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4t^4}+\frac{1}{t^2}}$$